# When does Laplace operator commute with isometries?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

let $(M,g)$ be a smooth compact Riemannian manifold and 
$$\phi:M\rightarrow M$$
an isometry. Let $u\in C^{\infty}(M)$, are there general conditions on $u$ and $\phi$ such that the following relation holds? 
$$\Delta_{g}\left( u\circ \phi \right)=(\Delta_{g}u)\circ\phi$$

Answer (score 4):

Always: the definition of $\Delta_g$ is in terms of $g$, so any diffeomorphism preserving $g$ preserves $\Delta_g$, and this is what ``preserves'' means.